# How to find Radii of Convergence for power series with alternating 0s

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, ratio

I was working on finding the Radius of Convergence of $\cosh{x}$, which is $1 + \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^4}{24}+ \frac{x^6}{720}+ \frac{x^8}{8!} + \cdots$.

The radius of convergence can be found with $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}\right|$, but because there are ALTERNATING 0's, this evaluates to 0 if n is odd, but $\infty$ when n is even...

For cosh x the radius is indeed infinity, but how can we use the above expression for the radius of convergence for a general power series with alternating 0 coefficients?

Comment: Radius of convergence is $\sqrt R$ where $R$ is the radius of convergence of $1+\frac x 2+\frac {x^{2}} {4!}+\frac {x^{3}}{6!}+...$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your series is $g(x)=f(x^2)$ with
$$f(y)=\sum a_ny^n,\quad a_n=\frac1{(2n)!}.$$
The radius of convergence of $f$ is $R=\lim\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=+\infty$, hence the radius of convergence of $g$ is $\sqrt R=+\infty$.

Comment: $a_n/a_{n+1}=(2n+2)(2n+1)$

Comment: @Empy2 Thank you! fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to apply the d'Alembert test to the numerical series. Then for $x\neq 0$ we get $${x^{2n+2}\over (2n+2)!}{(2n)!\over x^{2n}}={x^2\over (2n+2)(2n+1)}\to 0$$ Hence the
series is convergent for all $x,$ i.e. $R=\infty.$

The same method can be used to, for example, $\sum {x^{n^2}\over n!},$ where the method used in the comment by @geetha290krm is not available.